# R S4 class object function slot accessing function in another slot

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I want to be able to create an object in R with two 'layers' of functions. I have put together a very basic example below using an S4 class.

```
setClass("2layer_obj",
         slots = list(
           lower_functions = "list",
           higher_functions = "list"
         )
)

lower_functions <- list(
  function1 = function(x){
    x+2
  },
  function2 = function(y){
    y+6
  }
)

higher_functions <- list(
  function3 = function(z){
    test_obj@lower_functions$function1(z)+test_obj@lower_functions$function2(z)
  },
  function4 = function(z){
    test_obj@lower_functions$function1(z)-test_obj@lower_functions$function2(z)
  }
)

test_obj <- new("2layer_obj",
                lower_functions = lower_functions,
                higher_functions = higher_functions
                )

rm(lower_functions)
rm(higher_functions)

test_obj@higher_functions$function3(7)
```

My problem is that in order for this code to work I must put `test_obj@` before `lower_functions$function1(z)`. Therefore, if I were to re-run this code but change

```
 test_obj <- new("2layer_obj",
                lower_functions = lower_functions,
                higher_functions = higher_functions
                )
```

to

```
test_obj2 <- new("2layer_obj",
                lower_functions = lower_functions,
                higher_functions = higher_functions
                )
```

and tried to run `test_obj2@higher_functions$function3(7)`

It doesn't work because

```
Error in test_obj2@higher_functions$function3(7) : 
object 'test_obj' not found
```

So, my question is how can I create an object (with any of the OO class systems) in R where a function in one slot can run a function in another slot without having to use the name of the object?

Comment: This sort of thing is a lot easier with reference classes or R6 rather than S4. If you really want to use S4, then you will probably need Methods that apply the higher functions to the lower ones.